# Sonarqube is using Cobertura instead of Jacoco

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube, jacoco, cobertura

I'm trying to add a step in my Jenkins pipeline to upload the unit test report to Sonarcube.

- Project: Java 1.8.0_212
- Springboot: 2.1.6.RELEASE
- Sonarqube server: 6.7.6
- Sonarqube plugin: 2.8
- Jacoco plugin: 0.8.5

  ./gradlew sonarqube 
  -Dsonar.host.url=$sonarHostUrl 
  -Dsonar.language=java 
  -Dsonar.login=$token 
  -Dsonar.projectKey=$projectName 
  -Dsonar.projectName=$projectName 
  -Dsonar.projectVersion=$appVersion 
  -Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco 
  -Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths="./build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml"

For some reason Sonarqube is still looking for the Cobertura report.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths="build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml"

It should be like this other wise it tries to find from Jenkins home directory as cobertura is default with sonarqube

**make sure you have installed jacoco plugin on sonarqube server**

Comment: AFAIK Cobertura format is not a default for Java in SonarQube versions released during past years - https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.1/analysis/coverage/